# HTML Emails missing attachments

Tags: html, ruby, email

When I send an HTML email using Ruby 1.92 the attachments aren’t being displayed in some email clients. The attachment should be a pdf file. I can see the attachment in Outlook 2010 on an exchange server but not in yahoo web mail.

If I simply disable the HTML body everything works fine.

Here is the code:

```
require 'mail'

body_text = File.read('body.html')
subject_text = File.read("subject.txt")

Mail.defaults do
    delivery_method :smtp, { :address => "servername", :port => "25", :user_name => "name", :password => "password", :authentication => 'login'}
end

message = Mail.new do
    from ARGV[0]
    to ARGV[1]
    subject subject_text

    # if I comment out this section everything works fine
    html_part do
        content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
        body body_text
    end

    add_file ARGV[2]
end

message.deliver!
```

And here is the HTML Source:

```
<html>
<body>
<p style="font-family:trebuchet ms,helvetica,sans-serif;">Hello, <br />
<br />
This email was sent from Geiger and contains your A/R aged report for date. For any questions please call the Geiger helpdesk @ 207-755-2510<br />
Technical Details:<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sent from: Server_Name<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sent To: rep_id<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Original Email: to_email<br />
<br />
Helpdesk Please forward all enquiries to so and so<br />
<br />
<img src="http://www.geiger.com/logo.gif" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the output of message.to_s:

```
Date: Tue, 22 Nov 2011 08:22:52 -0500

From: wstaples@consoto.com

To: WSTAPLES@consoto.COM

Message-ID: <4ecba22c9ecb3_1cec974ab4171df@GBFA100016.mail>

Subject: Your  report for November, 2011 - consoto Gets it!

Mime-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: multipart/alternative;

 boundary="--==_mimepart_4ecba22c550e5_1cec974ab416812";

 charset=UTF-8

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit







----==_mimepart_4ecba22c550e5_1cec974ab416812

Date: Tue, 22 Nov 2011 08:22:52 -0500

Mime-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: text/plain;

 charset=UTF-8;

 filename=test_attatchment.txt

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Content-Disposition: attachment;

 filename=test_attatchment.txt

Content-ID: <4ecba22c75492_1cec974ab416991@GBFA100016.mail>



This is a test



----==_mimepart_4ecba22c550e5_1cec974ab416812

Date: Tue, 22 Nov 2011 08:22:52 -0500

Mime-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: text/html;

 charset=UTF-8

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Content-ID: <4ecba22c92576_1cec974ab41707b@GBFA100016.mail>



<html>

<body>

<p style="font-family:trebuchet ms,helvetica,sans-serif;">Hello, <br />

<br />

This email was sent from consoto and contains your  report for Nov 2011. For any questions please call the consoto helpdesk @ 207-755-2510<br />

Technical Details:<br />

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sent from: GBFA100016<br />

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sent To: BDB<br />

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Original Email: WSTAPLES@consoto.COM<br />

<br />

Helpdesk Please forward all enquiries to Wesley Staples or Shawn White<br />

<br />

<img src="http://www.consoto.com/logo.gif" /></p>

</body>

</html>





----==_mimepart_4ecba22c550e5_1cec974ab416812--
```

Comment: It could be some clients that remove it as spam?  What Mail library is this?  Perhaps the question should be directed towards the contact info for that library?

Comment: On a client that does see the message right, can you view raw source (including headers) and post the full raw message?

Comment: If you are using https://github.com/mikel/mail, then post the output of `message.to_s` (use a small txt file instead of a pdf)

Comment: Hi @DGM,

Yes this is the github.com/mikel/mail gem. Here is the output of message.to_s

Comment: FWIW, there are a lot of bugs with attachments. https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/search?q=attachment

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
```

Some mailers don't correct parse messages when these messages have content type "multipart/alternative" and attachments. In this case you have to create message with this structure:

```
 - multipart/mixed
  - multipart/alternative
 ...
```

You can do it like this:

```
unless mail_attachments.blank?
  mail.part :content_type => "multipart/alternative"  do |p|
    p.text_part = text_part
    p.html_part = html_part
  end
  mail_attachments.each do |file|
    mail.add_file file.local_path
  end
else
  mail.text_part = text_part
  mail.html_part = html_part
end
```

Comment: thanks for getting me on track. Thanks to you i found this section in the readme that has another example: https://github.com/mikel/mail#making-multipartalternate-without-a-block